# Can't use redis password with special characters in django

Tags: python, django, django-redis

I have a redis server with authentication password containing `=`, and `?`. Meanwhile I am using the Location scheme as `redis://[:password]@localhost:6397`.

Config:

```
'default': {
   'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
   'LOCATION': 'redis://:6?V4=434#ef4@localhost:6379/1',
   'OPTIONS': {
       'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.DefaultClient',
   }
},
```

I always get an error `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'V4'`. Somehow the Location scheme string doesnt count for cases where password have `=`, and `?` in certain order, such that it thinks it is separators in the scheme.
I tried to escape the special characters : `6\?V4\=434#ef4` but it gave me different error: `ValueError: Port could not be cast to integer value as '6\\'`

Can this be solved without moving password in `OPTIONS` ?

Answer (score 0):

so the solution is to use the `PASSWORD` in `OPTIONS` and remove the password from redis's url:

```
'default': {
   'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
   'LOCATION': 'redis://localhost:6379/1',
   'OPTIONS': {
       'CLIENT_CLASS': 'django_redis.client.DefaultClient',
       'PASSWORD': '?V4=434#ef4',
   }
},
```